# Registry and module error installing Natlink (Python 38 on Windows 10)

Tags: python, installation, module, windows-10, registry

Recently, I have had to reinstall the operating system on my machine. In the process I upgraded Dragon NaturallySpeaking (DNS) from v13 to v15 and in reconfiguring my voice recognition environment (DNS + Natlink + Dragonfly) the following Natlink message now appears on DNS start:

```
Failed to find Natlink key in Windows registry.
Failed to extract value from Natlink key.
An exception occurred loading 'natlinkmain' module
Error message:
No module named 'natlinkmain'
```

--

My DNS version: 15.61.200.010

My OS specifications:

- Edition: Windows 10 Pro
- Version: 20H2
- Installed on: 3/‎12/‎2021
- OS build: 19042.867
- Experience Windows Feature Experience Pack: 120.2212.551.0

--

To troubleshoot I have:

1. Reinstalled Python and Natlink several times to ensure that I'm installing correctly (per the [NatLink installation instructions](https://github.com/dictation-toolbox/natlink#instructions-for-end-users)):

Python 3.8.8 (32-bit), all users, at C:\Python38-32

I also cleared my system of all Python and Natlink remnants and restarted the operating system with each reinstall.

Everything I have attempted has been with OS administrative privileges.

2. Added additional system path variables in the following order:

```
    C:\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\natlinkcore\
    C:\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\
    C:\Python38-32\Scripts\
    C:\Python38-32\
```

3. Added the following registry entry:

[image: Registry Entry]

This last effort advanced initialization past the first message above to this new DNS startup Natlink message:

```
An exception occurred loading 'natlinkmain' module
Error message:
no module named 'natlinkmain'
```

4. Attempted to import natlinkmain:

[image: Python Import]

The referenced line...

[image: Line 113]

--

Additional information...

I did notice that using `C:\Python38-32\Scripts\start_natlinkconfig.exe` to configure Natlink produces the following error message only on the first initialization attempt:

[image: Error Message]

The executable would also produce two GUI configuration windows, but run successfully despite the error message and the two windows.

The corresponding message in `.natlink\configurenatlink_error.txt`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python38-32\lib\site-packages\natlinkcore\ConfigureNatlink\configurenatlink.pyw", line 1355, in <module>
    app = MyApp(True)
  File "C:\python38-32\lib\site-packages\wx\core.py", line 2137, in __init__
    self._BootstrapApp()
SystemExit: OnInit returned false, exiting...
```

The settings in `.natlink\natlinkstatus.ini`:

```
[usersettings]

NatlinkPydOrigin = C:\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\natlinkcore\PYD\natlink_3.8_Ver15.pyd
```

--

At this point I am out of ideas and am wondering if anyone has come across this error message before and resolved, or have any ideas on how I might resolve it? I need Natlink to successfully launch in order to run Dragonfly word macros.

In troubleshooting I have referenced the following issue:

https://github.com/dictation-toolbox/natlink/issues/20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Natlink is 32-bit, we have to modify a different location in the registry. [See here for more info.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/deployment/view-system-registry-with-64-bit-windows) You want to add a key at `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Python\PythonCore\3.8-32\PythonPath\Natlink` with the value `${PYTHON_INSTALL_DIRECTORY}\Lib\site-packages\natlinkcore` (`C:\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\natlinkcore` in your case).

[screenshot of registry editor - note that I installed Python in a different directory from you](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wl7Th.png)

I've been getting the same exact error as you and this is what finally fixed it for me today. I wonder if this was a bug introduced by a recent change, since I imagine Natlink is supposed to do this automatically.

Comment: Yes! Thank you. That did the trick. For those following along, the mistake I made was to add a specific file to the registry entry which allowed me to get past the initial error, but then produced the second error. The solution was to specify the folder, i.e. not the file. Thanks for taking the time to help me @Mike.